# Python performance profiling (file close)

Tags: python, performance, file, profiling

First of all thanks for your attention. My question is how to reduce the execution time of my code.

Here is the relevant code. The below code is called in iteration from the main.

```
def call_prism(prism_input_file,random_length):
   prism_output_file = "path.txt"
   cmd = "prism %s -simpath %d %s" % (prism_input_file,random_length,prism_output_file)
   p = os.popen(cmd)
   p.close()
   return prism_output_file


def main(prism_input_file, number_of_strings):
...
  for n in range(number_of_strings):
        prism_output_file = call_prism(prism_input_file,z[n])
        ...

  return
```

I used statistics from the "profile statistics browser" when I profiled my code. The "file close" system command took the maximum time (14.546 seconds). The call_prism routine is called 10 times. But the number_of_strings is usually in thousands, so, my program takes lot of time to complete.

Let me know if you need more information. By the way I tried with subprocess, too. Thanks.

Comment: You should use subprocess regardless as that is the replacement for all the other ways of calling out with a process. But I don't think there is much you can do if you **must** use a system process. They are expensive.

Comment: If instead of prism you call some trivial command, like `echo`, will `p.close()` still take up this much time? Chances are the prism process just takes some long cleanup action on termination. BTW if prism calls do not depend on each other, you might seriously cut execution time by running several processes in parallel threads (e.g. on thread per core).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback on my question. Based on the comments that others provided I did a parallel version of my code, and the performance of the code indeed improved. Here is the snippet of the parallel version. Your feedback, if any, is welcome.

```
def call_prism(prism_input_file,random_length):
    ...   
    cmd = "prism %s -simpath %d stdout" % (prism_input_file,random_length)
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.poll()
    prism_output_lines = p.stdout.readlines()
    ...
    return ...

def call_prism_star(prism_input_file_random_length):
   return call_prism(*prism_input_file_random_length)

def main(prism_input_file, number_of_strings,number_of_threads):
   pool = Pool(processes=number_of_threads)
   for n in range(0,number_of_strings,number_of_threads):
   ...
      for i in range(number_of_threads):
          a_args.append(...)
      output = pool.map(call_prism_star,itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(prism_input_file),a_args))
   ...
    return
```